Apache Karaf War deployment
I am trying to install web bundle in Apache Karaf 4.4.6
Every things woks fine excepts controller.
It's like seeing annotation and not register it. I tried my war in Jetty server and Tomcat and both works perfectly I don't know what is missing
mvn clean install 

and then
bundle:install -s webbundle:file:location.war?Web-ContextPath=tutorial-app

and it should direct you to /home but this is not working and actuator is working fine.
/**
 * 
 */
package com.swathisprasad.springboot;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePatternResolver;
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

import com.swathisprasad.springboot.controller.HomeController;


/**
 * @author Swathi
 *
 */
@Order(1)
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.swathisprasad.springboot.controller")
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HomeController h = new HomeController(); 
        System.err.println(h.home()+"111");
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    }
    
}

controller
@RestController
public class HomeController {
    
    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String home() {
    System.err.println("Test from deem");
        return "deem";
    }

}

pom.xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.swathisprasad.tutorial</groupId>
    <artifactId>tutorial-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>tutorial-server</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
       <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
<!-- 

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
     -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.swathisprasad.tutorial</groupId>
        <artifactId>tutorial-web</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
   
   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
 <!-- 
    -->
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                  <execution>
                      <id>copy-resources</id>
                      <phase>validate</phase>
                      <goals><goal>copy-resources</goal></goals>
                      <configuration>
                          <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/resources/static/</outputDirectory >
                          <resources>
                              <resource>
                                  <directory>${project.parent.basedir}/tutorial-web/src/main/web/dist/np-app/</directory >
                              </resource>
                          </resources>
                      </configuration>
                  </execution>
            </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                <argLine>
                    --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
                </argLine>
            </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                  <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-*.jar</packagingExcludes>
                  <warName>tutorial-app</warName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
             
            
            
            
            
            <!--  
            
            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                 <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-*.jar</packagingExcludes>
                  <warName>tutorial-app</warName>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>tutorial-app</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Export-Package>
                            *
                        </Export-Package>

                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-artifacts</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifacts>
                                <artifact>
                                    <file>src/main/config/bundle.properties</file>
                                    <type>cfg</type>
                                    <classifier>properties</classifier>
                                </artifact>
                            </artifacts>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            
             -->
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>


You use:
Web-ContextPath=tutorial-app

According to OSGi CMPN, 128.3.1 WAB Definition:

The Context Path must always begin with a solidus ('/' \u002F). The Web Extender must not recognize a bundle as a Web Application unless the Web-ContextPath header is present in its manifest and the header value is a valid path for the bundle.

Change to:
Web-ContextPath=/tutorial-app

If this doesn't help, you need to provide logs and which features you have installed in your Karaf (you need pax-web-war and pax-web-http-jetty (or -tomcat or -undertow)).
